# How to override @apply directives in tailwindcss

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

Is it possible to override @apply directives?

I have this example: https://play.tailwindcss.com/kyu6CxnBzB

```css
.item {
  @apply text-black font-light text-opacity-80 py-4 bg-gray-100;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="item">About Us</li>
  <li class="item">Success stories</li>
  <li class="item text-red-50 bg-red-800">Contact</li>
  <li class="item">Blog</li>
</ul>
```

with this result:

[image]

when I expected

[image]

it seems like the value in the first class define with apply (item) takes precedence over any other class specified afterwards

how would you solve a scenerio like that? creating a component (I'm working with svelte) seems like an overwkill for this, and I´d like some way to avoid duplicating stuff like "font-sans text-black text-black text-opacity-80 my-4 hover:text-gray-800 hover:text-underline etc..."

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a property of CSS, not tailwind. The specificity of your selector is greater than that of tailwinds utility classes. You can use the `@layer` directive to fix this by defining your class like so:

```
@layer components {
  .item {
    @apply text-black font-light text-opacity-80 py-4 bg-gray-100;
  }
}
```

This declares your class before tailwind's utility classes and so should have lower specificity.

Reference: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#layer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, so if I understand correctly, the layer fecines the order in which they are defined in the resulting css, and hacing no layer means it goes to the end. right?

Comment: The directive simply tells tailwind to move the contents to wherever you are loading tailwind (`@tailwind components;` in this case). It will end up looking the same if you declared your class after `@tailwind components;` but before `@tailwind utilities;`

Comment: This works perfectly if only one class is used as selector. But if using chained selectors this doesn't work anymore. Don't know exactly how to work around this. https://play.tailwindcss.com/2nmGe5yad3

Comment: @Fabius did you ever find a solution to this? I've run into the same issue

Comment: @NicholasBetsworth not exactly a solution, but a workaround. If you're using JIT mode, you can prefix inline classes with `!` to mark them as important. There are other more intrusive ways of doing this, like setting all utilities as important in the tailwind config, but i dont like that very much and you can encounter unexpected behaviors if you didnt write your classes with that option in mind from the beginning. Check this question i asked and also the comments to the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69825111

Comment: I understand @Layers, but that is overriding global with global. Instead, how do you override a global directly in an HTML element with TW classes?