# Override Tailwind CSS @apply directive on chained selectors

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Is there any way to override `@apply` directive on chained selectors?

Example: https://play.tailwindcss.com/2nmGe5yad3

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li class="class-one class-two">Item 1</li>
  <li class="class-one class-two">Item 2</li>
  <li class="class-one class-two text-red-50 bg-red-800">Item 3</li>
  <li class="class-one class-two">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  /* also doesnt work with "li.class-one" selector, works only with ".class-one" selector */
  .class-one.class-two {
    @apply text-black bg-gray-100;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set `important:true` into tailwind.config,this [page](https://sebastiandedeyne.com/why-we-use-important-with-tailwind/) can help you.please look at below code:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  important: true,
  theme: {},
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure setting `!important` to every single utility is really a safe choice, as stated in the page you linked. In my case it breaks Alpine.js `x-show` if the `<div>` to which it is applied has a `display` class (like `block`), due to the fact that Apline.js sets `display: none;` and not `display: none !important;`. For the moment i'm using the `!` prefix wich is available with `JIT mode` and which is also mentioned in the page you linked but it feels like a hack: I still dont get why tailwind behaves differently if overriding a single class selector or a chained class selector.

Comment: can you set the dynamic class to solve this problem without !important like this:
`:class=""`?

Comment: In my case (which is quite different from the example i posted, that had the only purpose to explain the issue) i cant use a dynamic class. For the moment the `!` prefix is the best choice, but maybe i'll open an issue on the tailwind github page

Comment: there are several ways to solve it. 1) !important into tailwind config 2)dynamic class with `:class` 3)dynamic style with `:style` and finally 4)set ID for each tag . you can solve it with pure CSS if you wanna choice 3 or 4 ways.