# Cannot overwrite the @apply directive in tailwind css

Tags: tailwind-css

I have defined a class  like so

```
.card {
  @apply bg-slate-300;
}
```

when i used

```
<div className="card bg-black">
```

the div is not overwriting the bg-color of the card class. How to overwrite that?

Comment: try add ```!important``` or use [@layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67244926/how-to-override-apply-directives-in-tailwindcss).

Comment: could you elaborate please how to apply !important? i've tried 
```
.card {
  @apply bg-slate-300 !important;
}
``` 
but it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your card class in the @layer directive:

```
@layer {
  .card {
    @apply bg-slate-300;
  }
}
```

Here is a working example: https://play.tailwindcss.com/SUrcD5pyw2